Min date in consecutive group before breakage
There is 1 table wherein all these records are maintained for 1 employee. Due to one more column in this table which is not shown in this example the person has multiple rows for even 1 job , i.e. 2 rows for job J1 , 3 for Job J2 and again 2 rows for job J1 in order. The person switches from job J1 to J2 and then again J1.How to extract the required rows whenever a switch happens as I have to extract the min of that row when job is changed starting backwards from Dec month as the checking needs to be done within Jan to Dec.
So for J1 output should be 1 Sep 2021 is what I need as before that there is breakage in J1 job and for J2 job it is 1 Jul 2021 for that year
StDt             EdDt           Job      
1-Jan-21      31-Jan-21        J1          
1-Feb-21      30-Jun-21        J1          
1-Jul-21      30-Jul-21        J2          
1-Aug-21      15-Aug-21        J2          
16-Aug-21     31-Aug-21        J2          
1-Sep-21      1-Nov-21         J1          
2-Nov-21      31-Dec-21        J1


From Oracle 12, you can use MATCH_RECOGNIZE to perform row-by-row pattern patching.
If you want the earliest start date for each period of the same consecutive job then:
SELECT job,
       min_date
FROM   table_name
       MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
         ORDER BY stdt
         MEASURES
           FIRST(job) AS job,
           FIRST(stdt) AS min_date
         PATTERN (same_job*)
         DEFINE
           same_job AS FIRST(job) = job
       )

Or, in earlier versions using the LAG analytic function:
SELECT job,
       stdt AS min_date
FROM   (
  SELECT job,
         stdt,
         CASE LAG(job) OVER (ORDER BY stdt)
         WHEN job
         THEN 0
         ELSE 1
         END AS changed_job
  FROM   table_name
)
WHERE  changed_job = 1

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (StDt, EdDt, Job) AS
SELECT DATE '2021-01-01', DATE '2021-01-31', 'J1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-02-01', DATE '2021-06-30', 'J1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-07-01', DATE '2021-07-30', 'J2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-08-01', DATE '2021-08-15', 'J2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-08-16', DATE '2021-08-31', 'J2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-09-01', DATE '2021-11-01', 'J1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-11-02', DATE '2021-12-31', 'J1' FROM DUAL;

Both output:



JOB
MIN_DATE




J1
2021-01-01 00:00:00


J2
2021-07-01 00:00:00


J1
2021-09-01 00:00:00




If you only want the latest of those dates for each job then:
SELECT job,
       MAX(min_date) AS last_min_date
FROM   table_name
       MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
         ORDER BY stdt
         MEASURES
           FIRST(job) AS job,
           FIRST(stdt) AS min_date
         PATTERN (same_job*)
         DEFINE
           same_job AS FIRST(job) = job
       )
GROUP BY job

or:
SELECT job,
       MAX(stdt) AS last_min_date
FROM   (
  SELECT job,
         stdt,
         CASE LAG(job) OVER (ORDER BY stdt)
         WHEN job
         THEN 0
         ELSE 1
         END AS changed_job
  FROM   table_name
)
WHERE  changed_job = 1
GROUP BY job

Which both output:



JOB
LAST_MIN_DATE




J1
2021-09-01 00:00:00


J2
2021-07-01 00:00:00



fiddle

Can we do this without match recognize?

@AlkaOjha Updated with a second solution.

First determine the 'current' job:
SELECT Job AS current_job
FROM   my_table
WHERE  StDt = (SELECT MAX(StDt) FROM my_table)

Then, get the minimum start date for that job making sure that there are no successive job changes:
SELECT MIN(tb_1.StDt) AS last_break
FROM   my_table tb_1
WHERE  Job = (SELECT Job AS current_job
              FROM   my_table
              WHERE  StDt = (SELECT MAX(StDt) FROM my_table)
             )
  AND  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   my_table tb_2
                   WHERE  tb_2.StDt > tb_1.StDt
                     AND  tb_2.Job <> tb_1.Job);


Does this work for getting the job J2 start date?

This works only for the latest job. I'll be back on this
